# nedb Database not loading file in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, nedb

Anybody who's knowledgeable using NeDB?

```
import React from "react";
const Datastore = require("nedb"),
  database = new Datastore({ filename: "./database.db", autoload: true });

database.loadDatabase();

const App = () => {
  return <div>Hello</div>;
};

export default App;
```

I just want to load an empty database file..
I tried multiple ways of picking the file path but it doesn't seem to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a new database file won't work in the browser, you'll have to run that on the server to create a file:

On the server:

```
const Datastore = require("nedb"),
  database = new Datastore({ filename: "./database.db", autoload: true });
```

On the client:

```js
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  return <div>Hello</div>;
};

export default App;
```

On the client, you can use `nedb` to create an in-memory DataStore, but it won't be persisted to a file.

Comment: I do use a local host node server

Comment: But is this code running on the server, e.g. in an Express app? It looks like client side code, unless you’re server rendering React. If you’re using something like create-react-app or webpack-dev-server, you’ll need to have a separate server running to persist the DB.

Comment: See this answer for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41726825/8852158

Comment: oh really Good to know I'll try that out asap and thanks

Yeah I used create-react-app